Validating fields with PrimaryKeyRelatedField
I am working with a DRF serializer which includes a field with the PrimaryKeyRealtedField.
import stripe
from rest_framework import serializers
from subscriptions.models.subscription_product import SubscriptionProduct

class SubscriptionCheckoutSessionSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
   url = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
   success_url = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
   cancel_url = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)
   subscription_product = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    queryset=SubscriptionProduct.objects.all()
   )

def create(self, validated_data):
    print(validated_data)
    subscription_product = validated_data["subscription_product"]
    print(subscription_product)
    stripe_price = subscription_product.stripe_price
    print(stripe_price)
    print(stripe_price.stripe_id)
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        success_url=validated_data.get("success_url", None),
        cancel_url=validated_data.get("cancel_url", None),
        mode="subscription",
        line_items=[
            {
                "price": stripe_price.stripe_id,
                "quantity": 1,
            }
        ],
    )
    print(session)
    return session

The print statements all print their expected output and the created session is a valid one. However, I get a 500 status code with the following error:
KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field subscription_product on serializer SubscriptionCheckoutSessionSerializer.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the Session instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'subscription_product'."
Does anyone know what this error actually means and how to solve it? I don't understand how it's possible that the print statements work as expected but I still get a key error.
Full stack-trace:
{'success_url': 'http://success', 'cancel_url': 'http://cancel', 'subscription_product': <SubscriptionProduct: Subscription unlimited lessons>}
Subscription unlimited lessons
Internal Server Error: /subscriptions/checkout-session/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 446, in get_attribute
    return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 94, in get_attribute
    instance = instance[attr]
               ~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/stripe/_stripe_object.py", line 216, in __getitem__
    raise err
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/stripe/_stripe_object.py", line 204, in __getitem__
    return super(StripeObject, self).__getitem__(k)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'subscription_product'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 20, in create
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 555, in data
    ret = super().data
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 253, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 509, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 190, in get_attribute
    return super().get_attribute(instance)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/app/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/fittery-il7asoJj-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 479, in get_attribute
    raise type(exc)(msg)
KeyError: "Got KeyError when attempting to get a value for field `subscription_product` on serializer `SubscriptionCheckoutSessionSerializer`.\nThe serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Session` instance.\nOriginal exception text was: 'subscription_product'."
[03/Jun/2024 10:26:45] "POST /subscriptions/checkout-session/ HTTP/1.1" 500 179766


Please, [edit] the question and share the full traceback as code (not an image). Normally the Django error page has a function to turn the error in a text format that includes settings, traceback, etc.
